# ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, csv, datetime

What I am trying to do is:

> 1. Delete all rows where csv date is lower than 25.05.2016 23:59
> 2. Save the file with a different name

I have the following data in a csv in col `A`

```
WFQVG98765
FI Quality-Value-Growth
Some Random String 1

Datum
13-05-2016 23:59
14-05-2016 23:59
15-05-2016 23:59
16-05-2016 23:59
17-05-2016 23:59
18-05-2016 23:59
19-05-2016 02:03
.

.

.

.
```

This is what I have tried now

```
import csv
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

def is_date(string):
    try: 
        parse(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

'''
1. Delete all rows where csv date is lower than 25.05.2016 23:59
2. Save the file with a different name
'''

cmpDate = datetime.datetime.strptime('25.05.2016 23:59:00', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')

with open('WF.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
     csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     for row in csvReader:
         print (row[0])
         if is_date(row[0]) and not row[0].strip(' '):
```

> ```
>             csvDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S') 'Error Here : ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
> ```

I also tried this for the error line

> ```
>             csvDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')      'But got the same error
> ```

```
             if csvDate<cmpDate:
                 print (row[0]+'TRUE')
```

> Here how can I delete the row if the condition is true and finally save it with a different name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can analyse each row to compare the dates, and save the rows you want to keep in a `list`. You can then store those rows into a new csv file and delete the old one if you don't need it anymore.

Here's a snipped that does what you're asking for:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

cmpDate = datetime.strptime('25.05.2016 23:59:00', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')


def is_lower(date_str):
    try:
        csvDate = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
        return (csvDate < cmpDate)
    except:
        pass

with open('WF.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    data = [row for row in csvReader if not is_lower(row[0])]

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    [writer.writerow(row) for row in data]
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't why it leaves a blank row between the two row and this doesn't actually works i.e. in the output.csv file I have all the rows from the input file :/

Comment: @newguy does your input csv use `,` as delimiter? does it have a date in the first row? can you put the first few lines from your csv file with a header?

Comment: The question has the exact text what is in the csv column A and yes `,` is the delimiter for  my csv

Answer (score 2):

`is_date()` is giving you *false positives*. Be more strict when you check the date format and consistent when you load a date string into `datetime` - follow one of the principles of [`Zen of Python`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) - "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it":

```
def is_date(date_string):
    try: 
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

In other words, don't mix `dateutil.parser.parse()` and `datetime.datetime.strptime()`.

Answer (score 2):

The `datetime.datetime.strptime` exception indicates you are passing a blank string to the function in `row[0]`.

Once you get that issue resolved, you need to add code to write acceptable rows to a new file.

Comment: Yes I know that maybe the error but shouldn't this line `if is_date(row[0]) and not row[0].strip(' '):` take care of that ? i.e. if the row has blanks it won't execute it

Comment: The `not` does the opposite of what you want it to do.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing the wrong comparison when you call `strip`. Two things:

- First of all, just use `row[0].strip()` (with no arguments). This will strip *all* whitespace (like newlines, etc), not just spaces.
- Secondly, `if is_date(row[0]) and not row[0].strip(' ')` only passes when `row[0]` is empty, which is the opposite of what you want. This should be `if row[0].strip() and is_date(row[0]):`

---

Even better, given how your `is_date` function is implemented, you should probably just put your datetime creation into a function that handles errors. This is my usual pattern:

```
def parse_date(str_date):
    try: 
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(str_date, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
    except ValueError:
        return None

cmp_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('25.05.2016 23:59:00', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')

output_rows = []
with open('WF.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        csv_date = parse_date(row[0].strip())  # returns a datetime or None
        if csv_date and csv_date >= cmp_date:
            output_rows.append(row)

# Finally, write output_rows to the output file
```